# Como conectar XAMPP Android WiFi

Tags: mysql

Mi pregunta es ¿es posible abrir una pagina web creada en `xampp` desde mi laptop por medio de mi celular `Android` con solo utilizar la zona wifi de mi celular? Puesto que, como soy desarrollador principiante, me gustaría probar mi pagina web desde mi celular.

Comment: Si es posible o no hacer esto, espero me puedan ayudar dandome alternativas para hacerlo una solucion para poder hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Solo busca la ip local de tu laptop con XAMPP (apache y/o mysql montados) y buscala en tu telefono.

Puedes, montando XAMPP, corre los servicios desde tu laptop, si estás en Windows, debes buscar la IP de tu laptop en tu modem del ISP, o desde el mismo windows de hecho la encuentras en propiedades de la conexion el puerto 80 de tu laptop lo abre XAMPP en 127.0.0.1 que seria igual a la ip que asigna tu moden de internet, así puedes entrar desde tu android con esa ip (la de tu laptop), Así te carga el localhost desde tu laptop, por ejemplo yo en linux tengo

10.42.0.245 (ip local)

y está montado apache y mysql

Puedo conectarme a esa ip desde mi teléfono y puedo ver lo que esta en dicha ip montado, como ejemplo la ip donde tengo el localhost de 10.42.0.245 de la red local del modem. El mismo ejemplo funciona si montas un http://miservidorlocal o http://miotroservidorlocal en tu laptop. Puesto que los DNS(locales) lo comparten el modem-laptop-telefono puedes usar nombres de dominio locales, pero es tema aparte.

Comment: Ok mauricio de antemano te agradezco por tu tiempo, ahora bien quisiera que me confirmaras que lo unico que necesito es mi celular mi laptop y no requiero de un router u otro dispositivo fisico o virtual y si es nécesario confiurar algo extra en los archivos de configuracion de apache.

Comment: Explica bien tu problema, se explicito por favor. lee, XAMPP monta el servicio local (indico: "local" me refiero a tu red-router-wifi donde están tus dispositivos, tu celular y maquina con XAMPP que viene siendo el servidor (tu laptop) y tu cliente que es tu celular, es necesario que tengas tu rel local: router-modem-wifi del servicio de Internet y tu laptop con XAMPP montado que es el servicio (servidor) y para ver (puedes usar cualquier dispositivo para ver tu IP local, donde esta XAMPP). No necesitas configuraciones extras

Comment: Descripcion de lobque hago: enciendo la zona wifi de mi celular, enciendo el wifi de mi laptop, realizo la conexion como cuando le otorgo datos de internet a mi laptop por medio de mi celular luego en el navegador  (crome) de mi celular y luego escribo la ip que designa la conexion inalambrica seguido del puerto de mi apache que es 8080 y luego el nombre de la pagina web pero aparece error en la conexion. Ahora que leo tu comentario me pregunto si necesito un router o modem wifi aparte de mi celular

Comment: Si, necesitas las 3 cosas, tu router, laptop y celular.

Answer (score 1):

Si, lo único que tienes que hacer es meter el móvil en la misma red que el laptop (en tu aso, meter el movil en el wifi del propio laptop), abrir un navegador (Recomiendo google chrome) y poner la ip del servidor.

PD: En caso de haber cambiado los puertos del xampp, poner la ip, dos puntos y el puerto

Ej: 192.168.1.5:8080